# I am using styled from styled-components but it is not working. Can somebody tell me what i am doing wrong in this?

Tags: styled-components

It is showing me this error:

> Compiled with problems: ERROR in ./src/components/Login.js 18:18-32
> export 'default' (imported as 'styled') was not found in
> 'style-components' (possible exports: AutoComplete, Button, Icon,
> Input, Menu, Progress, Transition, Upload)

```
import styled from 'style-components';

const Login = (props) => {
    return(<Container>
        Content
    </Container>);
}
const Container = styled.section`
overflow : hidden;
display : flex;`;

export default Login;
```

Comment: It is showing me this error:  Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/components/Login.js 18:18-32

export 'default' (imported as 'styled') was not found in 'style-components' (possible exports: AutoComplete, Button, Icon, Input, Menu, Progress, Transition, Upload)

Answer (score 3):

You have imported styled-components incorrectly

use `import styled from 'styled-components';`

Comment: Thank you. Now its working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue. My mistake was installing "style-components" instead of "styled-components". Installing the later and importing styled from 'styled-components' was the fix.